# Boolean resets itself to false when getExtra is called

Tags: android, android-intent, boolean

When I invoke getExtras.getBoolean(key) for my isDeleted boolean, it keeps setting itself to false, even though I'm passing in true. Any insight on why this is occurring? I've tried a lot of other methods, but haven't been successful in keeping the boolean value TRUE.

Other Activity:

```
   public void deleteWorkout(View view)
    {
        intent.putExtra("listPosition", intent.getExtras().getInt("position"));
        intent.putExtra("isDeleted", true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Main Activity:

```
case(List): {
                if(resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    boolean isDeleted = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("isDeleted");
                    int listPosition = intent.getExtras().getInt("listPosition");
                    if(isDeleted)
                    {
                        adapter.remove(workoutList.get(listPosition));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
            default:
                break;
            }
```

Comment: try using `getBooleanExtra` and `getIntExtra`

Comment: Try this way : intent.getBooleanExtra("isDeleted",false);

Comment: Tip: whenever you call `getExtras()` it creates a clone of the extras bundle, so this operation is rather expensive. Call `getExtras()` only once or better just use `getBooleanExtra()`, `getIntExtra()`, etc.

Comment: where is the variable `intent` in your `switch case` being initialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you can fix this and understanding why might save you the headache again in the future.

`putExtras` isn't the same as `putExtra`.
So what's the difference?

`putExtras` will expect a bundle to be passed in. When using this method, you'll need to pull the data back out by using:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isDeleted");
```

putExtra will expect (in your case) a string name and a boolean value. When using this method, you'll need to pull the data back out by using:

```
getIntent.getBooleanExtra("isDeleted", false); // false is the default
```

You're using a mix of the two, which means you're trying to get a boolean value out of a bundle that you haven't actually set, so it's using the default value (false).

Comment: Aha! So in future cases just choose one or the other?

Comment: Yes. The key thing here is to notice that you're setting a bundle and then reading a value in the bundle when you call `getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(`, but for that to work, you need to pass a bundle and not a boolean :)

Answer (score 8):

There is two way pass/get data one activity to another activity.

1.add data to intent.

how to put :

```
intent.putExtra("listPosition", intent.getExtras().getInt("position"));
intent.putExtra("isDeleted", true);
```

how to get :

```
int listPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("listPosition",0);
boolean isDeleted = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isDeleted",false);
```

2.Add data to bundle and add bundle to intent.

how to put :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra("listPosition", intent.getExtras().getInt("position"));
bundle.putExtra("isDeleted", true);
intent.putExtras(bundle)
```

how to get :

```
int listPosition = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("listPosition",0);
boolean isDeleted = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isDeleted",false);
```

Comment: @user3101180,if my ans is resolve your problem and useful to you then you can approve and upvote my ans.

Comment: Didn't have any karma yet. Here you go