# TextView doesn't show any text

Tags: android, textview

I have 2 `TextView`s but one of them doesn't show any text. I see in `LogCat` that is there but on the app it doesn't show. I'm sure that the problem is in my `xml` file but I don't know what exactly. Also I saw a lot of posts like this here and I've tried different thing from them but non is helped me. Here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10.18"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pressMe"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/PressMe" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dontPress"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/DontPressMe" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The problematic `TextView` is `"@+id/name"`

Also I get them from another activity via `putExtra` and `getExtra`

```
intent.putExtra("text", stocks[position].text); 
intent.putExtra("name", stocks[position].name);
```

and

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        name = b.getString("name");
        textView.setText(name+"");
        text = b.getString("text");
        textView.setText(text+"");
```

So the `text` is there but `name` is missing. On the first Activity both are there.

```
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Comment: can you put activity code?

Comment: try setting TEXT in XML only..Is it visible ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay .. my PC crash. Yes when I put text in xml they are visible both. One under another as should be.

Comment: can you tell me  what is there in `stocks[position].name` here `intent.putExtra("name", stocks[position].name);` ?

Comment: @Goro just try once my answer i did seen your code

Comment: I think object you need to create two textview object.Try this,           textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
textViewText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861117/boolean-resets-itself-to-false-when-getextra-is-called/26861319#26861319

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in your Layout

but the problem is in your code, you have to find both the textView in your oncreate method.
 you did find both, but the problem is that when you set the text, with the same reference of text

here you to take the same reference for both text view. change it like this.

```
TextView txtName = (TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.name);
TextView txtText = (TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.text);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            name = b.getString("name");
           //change here txtName.setText(name+"");
            text = b.getString("text");
            //change here txtText.setText(text+"");
}
```

Comment: Like this is working and name is also there. But why only one textview doesn't show in this case?

Answer (score 2):

```
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
```

Why you have that?

Try removing it or changing it for:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

Comment: Why should I use `marginBottom` instead of `paddingBottom`? I use padding because I want space between content and the view..

Comment: A padding goes inside the layout, so if your text is really there but doesn't show chances are it has not enough space. A margin goes outside the layout. Is not that you should never use it.

Comment: Yes, I understand now what you mean with your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting texts in the same TextView object using this:

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(name+"");
textView.setText(text+"");
```

Keep two separate textview and do this:

```
TextView textview1, textview2;
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView1.setText("name");
textView2.setText("description");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer also. I didn't know that this will overwriting texts.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_add_contact"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="dsgdsfgdfhdgfhfjhgfj" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="sfgdfhgfjgfjhgjhg" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pressMe"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="PressMe" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dontPress"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="DontPressMe" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView txtCont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Comment: Yes, I have them both. Updated in my question

Answer (score 1):

change this code may help you,

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        name = b.getString("name");
        ((TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.name)).setText(name+"");
        text = b.getString("text");
        ((TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.text)).setText(text+"");
```